# Swift MapKit region difference

Tags: swift, mapkit

I'm trying to load places from my backend if the map region changes.
Currently it's loading the places for the visible region like this:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
    let visibleRegion = mapView.region
    self.parent.loadPlaces(for: visibleRegion)
}
```

This solution is working but it loads everything again even if the map changes only a little bit. How can I only load the new visible region excluding the last region?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bC6zI.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). However, you would generally keep your region as a `@State var` in the `UIViewRepresentable`.

Comment: Hi. I already tried a bit. My idea is to save the previous region in a `@State var` and then compare it with the new region. But i'm not sure how to get the new area (blue in my example image).

Comment: Please read the links I posted in my comments. You are nowhere near asking this question so you can get assistance.

Comment: We have no idea how your loadPlaces function works, but keeping track of which regions have been loaded and just loading the intersections seems unnecessarily complicated. I would add a check to only reload regions once the change is significant (either a big distance or a change in size) and just remove duplicates.

Comment: Adding only new annotations (and maybe removing exactly those you don't need) is actually a good idea. If you just replace your annotations with the new search result, mapView recalculates your clusters which creates an annoying flickering for the user. Please specify the numbers of annotations you have. If not to many, it might be good to load just all.